# Error in installation of caffe on fedora 21

Tags: installation, package, caffe

[image]

I have tried to build caffe for python on my fedora 21(without GPU) for quite some time with no success. Can someone please help me on this?

Few of the commands that I have executed are:

```
git clone git://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS
cd OpenBLAS
make FC=gfortran
make PREFIX=/opt/openblas/ install
make clean
make all
```

On running the 'make all' command I get the result as shown on the terminal screen.
But OpenBLAS seems to be present at location /opt/openblas and I found cblas.h file at /opt/openblas/include. Then why do I get such an error?
To try to fix this, I added the following lines to my ~/.bashrc file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/opt/openblas/lib\:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export INCLUDE=$HOME/opt/openblas/include\:$INCLUDE
```

I also executed the following on the terminal and got the output as below,

```
[root@parags-pc Parag]# echo $PATH
/opt/openblas/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Note: I have also installed atlas. But nothing has come to my rescue.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you give us some error messages, so we know what you have tried and what is going wrong?

Comment: As shown in the screenshot, it is not able to find the cblas.h file. But I have already cloned OpenBLAS and runned the make and make install command( /opt/openblas). When I run the 'make all' command I get the above error(screenshot)

Comment: You will need to add some code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Make.config file to reflect the changes. You will find a flag to select the BLAS library, set its  value as 'open'. Then uncomment the library path and include path and reflect the correct values for those variables.